# How do you get percentage of time left for carbon php? (Laravel 8.X)

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

So I have the following:

```
$timeLeft   = $queue->completed_at->diffInSeconds(now()); 

dd($timeLeft);
```

Where `$queue` is a model (Laravel) with the attribute of completed_at (datetime).

What I am trying to do is essentially: `now() / $queue->completed_at` as a percentage of time left till it's done. (ie, 0.75)

I have seen other solutions where they take `now - end time / start - end` (or something similar)

**Can I not accomplish the same thing with `now()` and `completed_at` ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can I not accomplish the same thing with now() and completed_at ?

No, you need a start-time to have a percentage.

In this example, `now()` minus start will give you the amount of time elapsed, which can be compared to the entire time to give you a percentage.

```
[==================|=========]
start              now       completed_at
```

Here, however, there's no percentage to calculate. You only have `now()` and `completed_at`.

```
|=============]
now           completed_at
```